# Magento 1.9.2.2 Upgrade from Magento Downloader returned conflict error

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.2.2

What can be the reason for the following error when upgrading through Magento Connect Manager? I was upgrading from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2

```
Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.1
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.1
Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.1
```

and so on.

I've tried via ssh like this

```
chmod +x mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage sync
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

It returned several errors like

```
scandir(): (errorno 2) No such file or directory in /pat/to/the/server/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243
```

and then it is finished with success.

What experience did you have?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the top of these errors, there is an error showing that the `magento_all_lates.txt` can't be deleted from `/pkginfo`.
Once you do that manually, it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting both the Mage_All_Latest.txt folder as well as the text file manually enabled the patch to correctly install from Magento Connect Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear: the exact location of the files is in the root directory of Magento: /pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt